# Filter multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get two values from a multidimensional array below. I decode the JSON and then I try to filter it, however, I don't get any values then. Can you help me to fix this bug?

I try to get the email value and product name. What I thought is to get it with implode

```
$string=implode(', ', array_column($obj, 'email'));
```

This is my array

```
{
  "key": "sendMail",
  "cartItems": [
    {
      "bezeichnung": "test",
      "productname": "IGLO 5",
      "producttype": "Kunststoffsysteme",
      "windowtype": "Quadratisch",
      "typeopen": "rechts_kipp_open_mitte",
      "windowlong": "1000",
      "windowwide": "500",
      "dichtungen": "schwarz",
      "dekorfarbe": "",
      "outColorIn": "Grau",
      "outColorOut": "Grau",
      "selectedGriffe": "Standardgriff",
      "selectedOrnament": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedVerglasung": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedKante": "keine",
      "selectedSprossentyp": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedSprossenmuster": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedSprossenfarbe": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedRahmenLinks": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedRahmenRechts": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedRahmenOben": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedRahmenUnten": "Keine Angaben"
    }
  ],
  "personalData": {
    "name": "Hans Muster",
    "email": "hans.muster@email.ch",
    "tel": "0790012345",
    "agb": true
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, Show us your tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like a JSON object, simply do `$json_obj = json_decode($string);` and then

```
echo $json_obj->personalData->email;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $json_obj->cartItems[0]->productname;
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/arYuk)**

Outputs:

```
hans.muster@email.ch
IGLO 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$json = 
'{
  "key": "sendMail",
  "cartItems": [
    {
      "bezeichnung": "test",
      "productname": "IGLO 5",
      "producttype": "Kunststoffsysteme",
      "windowtype": "Quadratisch",
      "typeopen": "rechts_kipp_open_mitte",
      "windowlong": "1000",
      "windowwide": "500",
      "dichtungen": "schwarz",
      "dekorfarbe": "",
      "outColorIn": "Grau",
      "outColorOut": "Grau",
      "selectedGriffe": "Standardgriff",
      "selectedOrnament": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedVerglasung": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedKante": "keine",
      "selectedSprossentyp": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedSprossenmuster": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedSprossenfarbe": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedRahmenLinks": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedRahmenRechts": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedRahmenOben": "Keine Angaben",
      "selectedRahmenUnten": "Keine Angaben"
    }
  ],
  "personalData": {
    "name": "Hans Muster",
    "email": "hans.muster@email.ch",
    "tel": "0790012345",
    "agb": true
  }
}';
$json_array = json_decode($json,true);
echo $json_array['cartItems'][0]['productname']."<br>";
echo $json_array['personalData']['email'];
?>
```

The above code will give you the answer.